# How to manage the plugin managers in VIM?

Tags: vim

I know it may sound silly, but I am curious to find out if there is a framework already in place to help VIM users manage their plugin managers.

So, I know that there are plugins like "Vundle", "Pathogen" and "Neobundle" etc. for this purpose. I have been looking in those tools for the last couple of days. And they are great. My question is, are there any higher-level scripts designed to streamline the plugin loading process utilising any of the above mentioned plugin managers.

All the "Bundle Managers" have internal functions provided for unloading and loading plugins, manipulating RTP etc. Just wanted to check before going and starting to write my own vim script.

I am mainly interested in hearing about techniques using "Neobundle". I know that "janus" is doing exactly what I am asking for. It runs it's own functions to create plugin groups and access pathogen functions. So it is a bit like a front-end for pathogen.

A nice case would be:

Let's assume that you have installed plugins "A", "B", "C" and "D" using "Neobundle", however you would like to disable plugin "B" at start-up. But then enable it later. Everytime you will have to go into your .vimrc and comment out (or in) that line which is responsible for loading plugin "B"? or run the "Neobundle" function responsible for unloading that specific plugin?

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have that many badly written plugins that you need not one but two freaking levels of abstraction for "managing" them?

Anyway, I don't think there is one real "super manager" because there's no such thing as a unified plugin management API in the first place and… the lack of such an API is probably the reason why there are so many variations on the same theme.

Because Pathogen was the first in that series (there are older attempts like the built-in GLVS, yeah, no one knows about it…) and stayed alone for a while, the only thing that seems to be "standard" is the `bundle` directory. IMO, that would make a weak starting point.

I've seen a few Pathogen frontends attempts in the past, though, so there's a "chance" that progress is coming in this field.

- [microbe](https://github.com/xsc/microbe-vim)
- [pandemic](https://github.com/jwcxz/vim-pandemic)

There are others, browse r/vim for an hour and you will find many…

Comment: Thanks! I just need a tidy way of organising my dot files.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern (i.e. Vim 7.x), well-written plugin should only define its mappings and commands in the plugin script, and load its functionality on-demand via the *autoload* mechanism. Functionality that is specific to a particular filetype should only apply there via `ftplugin` scripts.

Unless you do crazy stuff like having the same mappings for two then mutually exclusive plugins, I don't see a need to dynamically enable / disable plugins. Don't make things more complex than they have to be. If you really have two disjunct editing use cases, I'd rather create two separate `~/.vimrc` files and aliases to use them.